# Guard clause on lists using only functional programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

The problem I am facing is that, given a list and a guard condition, I must verify if every element in the list passes the guard condition.

If even one of the elements fails the guard check, then the function should return `false`. If all of them pass the guard check, then the function should return `true`. The restriction on this problem is that **I can only use a single return statement**.

My code:

```
def todos_lista(lista, guarda):
  for x in lista:
    return(False if guarda(x)==False else True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
def todos_lista(lista, guarda):
    return all(guarda(x) for x in lista)
```

Or in a more functional way:

```
def todos_lista(lista, guarda):
    return all(map(guarda, lista))
```

For example for range 0 to 9 (`range(10)`):

```
>>> all(x < 10 for x in range(10))
True
>>> all(x < 9 for x in range(10))
False
>>> all(map(lambda x: x < 9, range(10)))
False
>>> all(map(lambda x: x < 10, range(10)))
True
```

Comment: I didn't know that python function but thank you for telling me that, yet it now presents an error saying Bool object not iterable

Comment: That means guarda isn't a function that takes an input and returns a boolean

Comment: @Pmsmm you seem to be passing it a single value, not a list.

Comment: That was exacly the answer, thank you very much. To sum it up, to be able to do this, the most simple answer is to use map alongside all to be able to check if all the arguments are True correct ?

Answer (score 2):

`any` will do the job as well:

```
def todos_lista(lista, guarda):
    return not any(not guarda(x) for x in lista)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `not any` to fulfil the requirement?

Comment: @bereal...actually it should be `not any(not x for x in l)`...same as `a and b and c == not (not a or not b or not c)` ... way too complicated I guess !